# styling django forms using reactjs

Tags: html, css, django, reactjs, frontend

I learnt about django-forms, and I wanna create a form which looks nice, styling with css and bootstrap and html.
but I found that out that I can't do it clean (like creating separate css sheet for styling) and I have to do it through python code which is doesn't look good.
is there any way to do this? if I try to handle the whole frontend, do I still need to set some styles through python in backend including django forms?
I'm sorry if it is a dumb question but I'm new to reactjs(actually I didn't learn it yet) and I have just a little experience in django.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do this through Python code and who says that you can't create separate CSS style sheets?

Just use a template which is then loaded in Django. Within the template you can take each and every input field from your forms.py and show it separately by adding

```
{{ form.first_field }}
```

for example. If you want to learn more on this [read the documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

Separate CSS sheets, you can just include in the head of the HTML template.